# R waldo does not find difference that snapshot test finds in .RData file

Tags: r, git, snapshot, testthat

looking for a bit of support:
I have done some `expect_snapshot_file()` tests from the `testthat` package - and the files end up not matching when being done in different RStudio sessions (I'm guessing that this is related to this).

I opened both files (the original and the `.new` file) and attempted to compare them using `waldo::compare(old,new)` - but waldo does not find any differences in the files. Both the snapshot tests and my `git` system also notes that these files are different, but again I don't know why/where in the file. **Note:** It is possible to recreate the difference when setting all this up in a git folder - commit the `outcomes.RData` file, then rename the `outcomes.new.RData` file to `outcomes.RData`and then `git` will display a difference - but again because it's a binary file, it won't tell me where...

I cannot use the `snapshot_review()` function because it does not seem to work with `.RData` files - it immediately gives me a complicated error.

So I would like to investigate where the differences are. I presume that it might be something related to the R session that I'm working in.

I have provided both files here:

https://transfer.sh/7UwTLD/outcomes.new.RData

https://transfer.sh/xgqhL7/outcomes.RData

and then compare them:

```r
download.file("https://transfer.sh/xgqhL7/outcomes.RData", destfile = "outcomes.RData")
download.file("https://transfer.sh/7UwTLD/outcomes.new.RData", destfile = "outcomes.new.RData")

load("outcomes.RData")
old <- outcomes

load("outcomes.new.RData")
new <- outcomes

waldo::compare(old, new)
#> v No differences
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The original saving function always stays the same:

```r
save_file <- function(outcomes){
    path <- tempfile(fileext = ".RData")
    save(outcomes, file = path)
    path
  }

expect_snapshot_file(save_file(outcomes), name = "outcomes.RData")
```

Is there any other way that `snapshot` uses "under the hood"? What other aspects could I consider?  Are there any other tools how I could compare files under Windows in a useful manner?

Many thanks!